# Hyphenated subscript term in Matlab

Tags: hyphenation, subscripts, matlab

Around 2014, the LaTeX engine Matlab uses was modified significantly.  As a result, I believe there is no longer a way to use the `amsmath` package from within Matlab.

Without the `amsmath` package, how can one make a hyphen appear in subscripted text?

Comment: May be closed as off-topic, but in MATLAB R2016a, I see the expected hyphen when I use `xlabel('x_{a-b}')`. What's the issue?

Comment: If I want to type, for example, `xlabel('$x_{a\mathrm{-test}}$','interpreter','latex')`, then the hyphen is interpreted as a minus sign.  I would like it to be interpreted as a hyphen that is appropriately sized without having to depend on the `amsmath` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `` \mathchar`- ``:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

$x_{a\mathrm{\mathchar`-test}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]